# Что нужно знать о защите веб-сайта / веб-приложения?

Tags: php, защита

Скажите пожалуйста, что нужно знать для того, чтобы защитить своё веб-приложение. Недавно написал свой mvc-движок на php и очень хотелось бы создать для него хорошую системы защиты. Заранее спасибо...

Comment: изучить все существующие виды атак и закрыть все дырки в коде

Comment: Для начала, следовало бы уточнить, от чего вы хотите защитить приложение: от атак или копирования?